# d3.selectAll().data(myDataSet).enter().append("rect") is selecting the previously created rectangles instead of myDataSet

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, attributes

I am new to **d3.js**, currently I am working in a project which needs **d3.js**. I am facing a problem need help / guidance to solve this.

The problem is ***in my svg container I have 2 hard-coded rectangles [created with svg.append("rect")].***

Now I have a `json dataset` which has `2 data to create another 2 rectangles[` there might be more data in json at runtime, this is static example].

Now when I use the following code it only creates 1 rectangles.

Notice The selectAll function on svg selects the other 2 previously created rectangles and only dynamically creates the extra `1 rectangles (3 in json - 2 hardcoded rectangles = 1 rectangles created).`

But I want that all the `data (3)` in json should created a rectangle that is `3 rectangle` should be created by Json and the hardcoded rectangles should remain as it is.

But it is not doing that, I have added the html code this post. Here is my javascript and HTML what i have tried so far.

Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>D3 Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello....</h1>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var w = 1000;
  var h = 400;
  var svgContainer = d3.select("#chartDiv").append("svg").attr("width",     w).attr("height", h);          

     var call_result_dataset = [{"x_axis":40, "y_axis":10, "width":5, "height":110, "color":"green"},
                                {"x_axis":700, "y_axis":10, "width":5, "height":110, "color":"red"},
                                {"x_axis":760, "y_axis":10, "width":5, "height":110, "color":"red"}];

     var call_result_strip = svgContainer.append("rect")
                                        .attr("id", "call_result_strip")
                                        .attr("x", 10)
                                        .attr("y", 10)
                                        .attr("width", 980)
                                        .attr("height", 110)
                                        .attr("fill", "rgb(235,235,235)");

     var call_type_strip = svgContainer.append("rect")
                                        .attr("id", "call_type_strip")
                                        .attr("x", 10)
                                        .attr("y", 200)
                                        .attr("width", 980)
                                        .attr("height", 110)
                                        .attr("fill", "rgb(235,235,235)");



     var call_result_strip_bars = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                                              .data(call_result_dataset)
                                              .enter()
                                              .append("rect");

         var all_r_strip = call_result_strip_bars.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x_axis;})
                                        .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y_axis;})
                                        .attr("width", function(d){ return d.width;})
                                        .attr("height", function(d){ return d.height;})
                                        .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.color;})
                                        .attr("id", function(d,i) {return     "result_"+i;});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
svgContainer.selectAll(".dynamicRects")
.data(call_result_dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.addClass('dynamicRects')
...
```

This way, the enter selection will first be empty and then the three dynamic rects will be created.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you help with the dynamicRect css class. I mean what will be the code for it.

Comment: There need not be any code for the css class. Its just a marker class..See http://jsbin.com/EzEluVU/1/ for reference implementation

Comment: Maybe it's a version thing, but `.addClass(...)` is not defined in D3 3.5.3 - instead one uses `.classed(... , true)`. Are you sure you're not mixing up jQuery and D3?

Answer (score 2):

selecting nothing wit some class name will suit your requirment.

```
svgContainer.selectAll()
             .data(call_result_dataset)
             .enter()
             .append("rect");
```

it is recommended to use a class name for the selection and the code goes like..

```
svgContainer.selectAll(".someClass")
             .data(call_result_dataset)
             .enter()
             .append("rect").classed("someClass",true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bharadwaj. Your suggestion also works properly just we need to omit the Quote in the selectAll() insteadof selectAll("").